# Websockets client for Wemos D1 R32

Tags: websocket, esp32, arduino-ide

I can't, for the life of me, find a library that allows me to implement a simple websocket client in a Wemos D1 R32 board (using Arduino IDE). I have tried several of them and ALL of them fail to connect to the websocket and send a message. Just the plain example code (modified only to change Wifi SID and password) does not work. For some reason, all of them seem to skip the onConnect socket event. I suspect that because, on the server side, I can see the sockets opening and closing, but on the client side I ALWAYS see "connection lost" but never "connection open".

Here is an example: https://www.mischianti.org/2020/12/07/websocket-on-arduino-esp8266-and-esp32-client-1/

If I copy and paste the example ESP32 code and change just

- The WiFi SID and password to match mine (lines 17 and 18).
- The server address and port to match mine (line 101).

It compiles and uploads without problems but it just doesn't work. No message is sent to the server and I suspect it's because the `connected` variable on line 112 is always false.

The server is continuously creating the WebSockets and opening the connection. Then closing it again (I SUSPECT the server is closing the connection when the client is trying to open a NEW one). Nevertheless, the client is NEVER printing the `"[WSc] Connected to url"` message on line 46, as if the client never realized the connection was open.

The server works pretty well with other clients (such as wscat or javascript clients) and is fully verbose to show every connection event and message received. Still, I can't get the D1 R32 to send a message to the server. I myself programmed the server extending NanoHTTPD WebSockets server (I mean, it COULD be possible something is wrong with the server, but it seems to work ok with other clients).

If I use HTTP GET requests, they work OK, but every request takes several seconds, and it's a bit too much. I thought using WebSockets would be better, but I can't work it out?

Is this a common problem? Any tips that can lead me a bit? I'm completely lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a common problem. Most likely suspect is your server, or the device's connection to it (firewall much?).

Comment: But the server is happily serving other clients... And the device is happily connecting to the SAME server on the SAME machine using HTTP GET.

Comment: OK. TBH "_I have tried several of them_" is a rather insufficient input data for a question. There's not much we can help you with until you post  your [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, I have added one of the examples I have tried that shows the described symptoms.